# How can I format my timestamp right?

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I have a timestamp from the mySQL database and I would like to format it.

```
$date = $row['date']; 
$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

My problem is now that it prints not the date of the database. Instead it prints out the current date. But this is not what I need.

So if I print this, I get the right date:

```
printf($row['date']);
```

But if I print this I get the right format but not the right date:

```
 printf($date);
```

Comment: What about giving the timestamp to the date() function... http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass that date, as a Unix timestamp, to `date()` as the second parameter. Otherwise `date()` has no idea you want to format a specific date:

```
$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($row['date']));
```

This assumes that `$row['date']` is in a [valid date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Answer (score 3):

Use this as `date()` requires a timestamp:

```
$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($row['date']));
```

Otherwise, the `time()` function will be used for the second parameter and outputs the current time. `$row['date']` should be either a PHP readable or a timestamp (in this case, you can leave `strtotime()` out).